# Can splitting a quasi-Newton optimisation into two stages improve the speed of convergence?

Tags: statistics, optimization, matlab, regression, parameter-estimation

I have a negative log-likelihood function $\ell(\mathbf{x}) = \ell(x_1, x_2, \dots)$, and I would like to find the parameter values that minimise $\ell$. I am wondering when it would be quicker to first find the value of $x_1 = \hat{x}_1$ that minimises $g(x_1) = \ell(x_1, 0, 0, \dots)$, and use the vector $(\hat{x}_1, 0, 0, \dots)$ as the start for the minimisation of $\ell(\mathbf{x})$. If the optimisation procedure is important, I am using the 'quasi-Newton' method in Matlab's `fminunc`.

For example, would this method help when we believe that $x_1$ is the regression coefficient of a covariate that has the biggest effect on the response?

Comment: No and you could have a case where for example one of the covariate has a big effect and a combination of other covariate has a big effect, in that case it might not help at all. It may help to lower the # of iterations in some cases but I don't think you can draw any kind of general principled heuristic. If you're really concerned about speed, consider using something better than Matlab+fminunc (eg Julia is great and has a similar syntax). Also if you're actually doing a regression I hope that you're not using fminunc for that!

Comment: Thanks. What other function should I be using for regression?

Comment: It depends on the regression, if it's a simple least-square type regression, you just need to solve a linear system, if it's a GLM then I'd recommend using a package such as the GLM package from R, regressions are very well studied problems and hence there are (lots of) packages that exploit their specific form while fminunc is a more generic tool that makes far fewer assumptions and can therefore be much slower. (Actually matlab, if you must, has GLMfit as well)

Comment: Ah, thanks. The regression I am trying to do does not fit in a standard  mould, e.g. poisson/logistic etc.

Comment: maybe describe what regression you're trying to do / objective function you're trying to minimize ? It may be non-standard but regressions typically follow a specific pattern with an objective function like $D+R$ where $D$ is some norm representing a data fitting term and $R$ is a regularization term (also typically some norm), if that's the case, you should exploit it. (But I understand you may be in a widely different case, and then I'm curious)

Comment: I can use expectation maximisation to maximise the likelihood. But, I have not coded it myself to do it, so I am just relying on fminunc for the moment.